# When dealing with methods in Javascript, why is this not setting a global variable?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

```
var setAge = function (newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};

var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;

bob.setAge = setAge; 

bob.setAge(50);
```

Basically, the code starts with a method that changes an age property, then the method is followed by a "bob" object, and finally there's a code that uses the method to change bob's property (age).

I have two questions about:     bob.setAge = setAge; (the second to last line in the code)

1. By setting setAge equal to bob.setAge, doesn't this set setAge to a global variable, equalling bob.setAge?
2. In bob.setAge, bob is the variable, and setAge is the method. I thought that when writing out something like bob.setAge, the word that comes before the period references the object (**susan**.age), and the word that comes after the period references a property (susan.**age**). How does javascript recognize that the setAge in bob.setAge references a method and not a property?

Comment: use `{}` instead of `new Object()`

Comment: @Phil Its shorter and it's better practice. *As far as I know*

Comment: @vihan1086 how does it help the OP?

Comment: 1) `setAge` is already global (in the scope of your question's code). You are not setting `setAge` to equal `bob.setAge`, you are in fact doing the opposite; you are setting the property `setAge` on object `bob` to equal `setAge` (the global function)

Comment: is this code executed in global scope? or is it in a module or function?

Comment: @KirillSlatin It's a comment, I'm just suggesting

Comment: have you try to query what `this` is when you call it via `bob.setAge(50);`?  I am expecting it to be bob... : `{ age: 30, setAge: function... }` and not `window' or whatever global object is.

Comment: @Phil what if i put the code in reverse order, i.e. setAge = bob.setAge. Will the behavior change? Am I still setting the property     setAge on object bob to equal setAge (the global function)?

Comment: @JimmyChandra: `this` should be `bob` if that is indeed the OP's code.

Comment: @gzaw StackOverflow isn't really the place for conjecture. All I will say is *try it and see for yourself*

Comment: @JimmyChandra when you call `this`, it  runs `bob`.

Comment: See my answer for explanation in code, run it with console window open. You see that `this` changes depending on how you call `setAge`

Comment: @Phil I tried the code, it didn't work. So I guess order does matter in Javascript. It baffles me how x=y is different from y=x, but that must be Javascript's behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> By setting setAge equal to bob.setAge, doesn't this set setAge to a global variable, equalling bob.setAge?

No, you're doing the opposite

> In bob.setAge, bob is the variable, and setAge is the method. I thought that when writing out something like bob.setAge, the word that comes before the period references the object (susan.age), and the word that comes after the period references a property (susan.age). How does javascript recognize that the setAge in bob.setAge references a method and not a property?

JS does not "recognize it" (it does not distinguish between "them" since "they" are the same thing): `bob.setAge` holds a reference to a function that you may (and you do) invoke

Answer (score 1):

```js
var setAge = function (newAge) {
  console.log(this);
  this.age = newAge;
};

var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;

bob.setAge = setAge; 

console.log('Calling set age as bob\'s method');
bob.setAge(50);  //this should be bob... 

//above is similar to the following
console.log('Calling set age with bob as scope');
setAge.call(bob, [ 50 ]);

console.log('Calling set age as a function with no context');
setAge(100);  //this should be global object since the function is called without any context / scope. In this case, it's the window object since we are running in a browser.  In node, it will be node itself, etc.
```

Comment: When I run it, I get `Calling set age as bob's method
{ age: 30, setAge: [Function] }` Why don't I get age 50? After all, it's `bob.setAge(50)` I am confused. help!

Comment: @gzaw because first the log happens, then `age` is assigned